# Wrong display of "shy" symbol

Tags: python, ascii, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

My page have `&shy;` symbols in every word. I am converting HTML page to PDF file using Python + wkhtmltopdf + pdfkit. Result of appearing `&shy;` looks like black square. How can I fix it?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: `&shy;` is a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen).

Comment: @Peter Wood Yes I know. It is okay in html file, but not okay in pdf.

Comment: @Aero this question isn't about you (c:

Comment: Have you seen [the issue on github](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1722)? Which version are you using?

Comment: @PeterWood I am using 0.12.2.2. Thanks for link, will try to find solution there.